# jQuery Syntax Error for custom wordpress script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Can anyone see why I'm getting a syntax error on line 19 of this piece of code? To give some context: it's a small javascript to get an image to appear in a random place, at a relatively random size, at a random orientation on a wordpress page. I'm getting an error on the `});` just after the `background url...` The main code appears within the  `//* Required *//` notes. Thanks in advance

```
( function( $ ) {
var body    = $( 'body' ),
    _window = $( window ),
    nav, button, menu;

nav = $( '#site-navigation' );
button = nav.find( '.menu-toggle' );
menu = nav.find( '.nav-menu' );

//*  Required *//

    (function makeDiv(){
        // vary size for fun
        var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
        $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
            'width':divsize+'px',
            'height':divsize+'px',
            'background-url’:’/wp-content/themes/idealpress/images/popup.svg'
        });

        // make position sensitive to size and document's width
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();    
        var rNum = (Math.random() * 360 ) + 1; 

        $newdiv.css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':posx+'px',
            'top':posy+'px',
            'display':'none',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'deg)' 
        }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100, function(){
          makeDiv(); 
        }); 
    })();
//* Required *//


} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: the commas after   'background-url’:’ are not right. change them to `'`

Comment: This site's syntax coloring should give you enough hint... or that in your IDE...

Comment: There are numerous resources available for validating syntax. Posting syntax problems here is ridiculous

Comment: Sorry everyone – I didn't realise – I'll check myself more thoroughly next time, still trying to learn the ropes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes.

Change this line:

```
'background-url’:’/wp-content/themes/idealpress/images/popup.svg'
```

into this:

```
'background-url':'/wp-content/themes/idealpress/images/popup.svg'
               ^ ^
```

Hence the JSON syntax is invalid.